# Notice: Undefined offset: 0....override/classes/Category.php on line 18

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i use prestashop 1.6.1.12
I use php 7.1

I have this error message 10 times:

`Notice: Undefined offset: 0....override/classes/Category.php on line 18`

category.php content is :

```
<?php
/**
*
*add function for image2 for for class product.php
*
**/
class Category extends CategoryCore
{
    public static function getProductsImgSupp($product_id)
    {
            $sql = '
            SELECT id_image, id_product from `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image`
            WHERE id_product="'.$product_id.'"
            ORDER BY `position` ASC
            LIMIT 1,1
            ';
            $result = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);
            return $result[0]['id_product'].'-'.$result[0]['id_image'];
    }
}
```

Is there a way to correct this error ?

Comment: `var_dump($result);` to check the value of variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql does not return any records.

2 Reasons for this:

1. There are no images in the table `...image` (which may be correct)

OR

2. The `product_id` which is getting passed to your method is not correct.

### How to fix?

Case 1:

```
$result = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);

if (empty($result)) {
    return null; // you may have to deal with this null if you arent already
}

return $result[0]['id_product'].'-'.$result[0]['id_image'];
```

Case 2:

Check the code which calls `getProductsImgSupp` to see if the right id is passed.